# SpriteKit Rotate Sprite depending on touch location

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a sprite which I can drag across the screen. My question is how to make it also to rotate automatically.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(_dead)
        return;

    NSArray *touchArray=[touches allObjects];
 if ([touchArray count] == 1)
    {
        [_player runAction:[SKAction moveTo:[[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self] duration:0.01]];
    }

}
```

Currently this is my code and it is working perfectly for draging.

Comment: rotate to the direction it is moving to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it shall in the same direction every time you can just call

```
_player.zRotation = valueBetween_0_and_1_
```

or

```
SKAction *rotation = [SKAction rotateByAngle: ANGLE duration:DURATION];
```

You can then write a Method to rotate the sprite depending on it's origin or move direction.

Comment: Ok but how to get the current angle of the touched location. Because when I am dragging the angle changes every 0.01 sec.